# jQuery Mobile restting form elements

Tags: jquery, forms, mobile, jquery-mobile, reset

I'm using jQuery Mobile (v1.1.1) to create a smartphone app but I'd like to have a "reset" button that clears a form that controls the app. E.g.

```
<label for="list1">Select an option</label>
<select id="list1" name="list1" data-native-menu="false" multiple>
<option value="1">option 1</option>
<option value="2">option 2</option>
<option value="3">option 3</option>
<option value="4">option 4</option>
</select>
```

I have not enclosed the above markup with

```
<form method="" action=""> ... </form>
```

(which is probably what JQM expects) because I'd like to do all processing on the client rather than sending stuff to a server.  I can read the options selected using some normal jQuery, e.g:

```
var vals = [];
$('select option:checked').each(function() {vals.push($(this).attr('value'));});
```

But I can't work out how to reset/clear all the above options should I click on a "reset" button.  I've tried:

```
$('select option').attr('checked', 'unchecked');
```

But this doesn't work.  Does anyone know how JQM  stores which options have been selected and how I can reset these options?

Thanks,
Stu

Answer (score 0):

I use that:

```
$('.ui-select a').find('.ui-btn-text').text('placeholder text')

$('.ui-selectmenu ul li[aria-selected="true"]')
    .attr('aria-selected', 'false')
    .removeClass('ui-btn-active');
```

Maybe it will be helpful.

**edit:**

I found also other solution:

```
    $('select option').removeAttr('selected');
    $('select').selectmenu('refresh', true);
```